# Which two straight lines satisfy the following condition?

Tags: geometry, functions, transformation, isometry

I have the following transformation:

$f(x,y)=(-\frac{3}{5}x+\frac{4}{5}y -\frac{4}{5},\frac{4}{5}x+\frac{3}{5}y+\frac{2}{5})$ which is the reflection on the the straight line defined by $y=2x+1$

I'm asked the following:
Give a pair of lines $m$ and $l$ for which the isometry $g=(R_l \circ f \circ R_m)^2$ satisfies $g(0,0)=(2,4)$ where $R_l$ denotes the reflection on the line $l$.

I have concluded that $R_l \circ f \circ R_m$ must be an inverse isometry, but not a reflection, otherwise $g(0,0)=(0,0)$, I guess it must be a glide reflection, but I don't know a smart aproach to find the straight lines $m$ and $l$.

Comment: Just checking: Is the goal to find _some_ pair of lines, or _all_ such pairs of lines? (Separately, in English the term is _glide reflection_.)

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang The question I have is to find just a pair (I'll correct the question) of lines. I would like to know which of those are easier to computer, or how to aproach this sort of problem.

Comment: It suffices to make $g$ a translation along $y = 2x + 1$, so it suffices to make $R_{l} \circ f \circ R_{m}$ a glide reflection along $y = 2x + 1$. An easy way to arrange this is to choose $l$ and $m$ perpendicular to $y = 2x + 1$.